# google cloud storage signed url for download facing CORS error

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, cors, google-cloud-storage

My react app makes POST request to server /signedUrl for creating a short-lived signed url that can be used to fetch files from firebase storage bucket.
My server is configured to allow request from any origin. The request to /signedUrl stays pending for 10 minutes and after that it shows 500 error and print this in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver.com/signedUrl' from origin 'https://myclient.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

However, this works fine in localhost but fails in hosted dev and prod environment. There are some other functions in my storageService.ts such as moveFile(), deleteFile(), deleteDirectory() and they works fine. When I return a dummyUrl from createTemporaryDownloadUrl() without involving the storage, it works fine too. At first I thought somehow it's not getting the `process.env.PROJECT_ID` but it's also required in the other service functions and since they're working well so I guess that's not the case here.

App.ts:

```
const app = express()
  .use(cors({ origin: true }))
  .use(express.json())
  .use(express.urlencoded())
  .use("/signedUrl", signedUrlRouter)
```

SignedUrlController.ts:

```
export const signedUrlRouter = express.Router();

signedUrlRouter.post("/", async (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> => {

  let fileIdWithPath: string = request.body?.fileIdWithPath || "";

  if (fileIdWithPath === "") throw new Error("Must provide a fileIdWithPath");

  const url = await createTemporaryDownloadUrl(Buckets.ORG, `${fileIdWithPath}`);
  response.status(200).send({ url });
});
```

StorageService.ts:

```
import { Storage, GetSignedUrlConfig } from "@google-cloud/storage";

export enum Buckets {
  ORG = ".appspot.com",
  // ... other buckets
}

const storage = new Storage();

const getBucketName = (bucket: Buckets): string => {
  return `${process.env.PROJECT_ID}${bucket}`;
};

export const createTemporaryDownloadUrl = async (bucket: Buckets, fileIdWithPath: string): Promise<string> => {
  const options = {
    version: "v4",
    action: "read",
    expires: Date.now() + 10 * 1000, // 10sec
  } as GetSignedUrlConfig;

  const [url] = await storage.bucket(getBucketName(bucket)).file(fileIdWithPath).getSignedUrl(options);
  return url;
};
```

cors config for bucket:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

bucket rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

OPTIONS general headers:

```
Request URL: https://myserver.com/signedUrl
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: ***.***.***.***:***
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

OPTIONS request headers:

```
:authority: dobee-dev.ew.r.appspot.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /signedUrl
:scheme: https
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,organizationid
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://myclient.web.app
Referer: https://myclient.web.app/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0
```

OPTIONS response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type,organizationid
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myclient.web.app
Alt-Svc: h3=":---"; ma=---,h3-29=":---"; ma=---
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 05:24:43 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: ----------
X-Powered-By: Express
```

POST General headers:

```
Request URL: https://myserver.com/signedUrl
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

POST Request headers:

```
:authority: myserver.com
:method: POST
:path: /signedUrl
:scheme: https
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/json
Dnt: 1
Organizationid: <orgID>
Origin: https://myclient.web.app
Referer: https://myclient.web.app/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?1
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Android"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0
```

Comment: None of this matters except the CORS configuration on your server. I can't find any clear docs about what `cors({ origin: true })` does - have you tried just using `app.use(cors())`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your code snippet labeled "cors config" is referring to. Can you include the response headers that you receive on the browser when you make a request to your server?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I've updated my question to include headers.

Comment: It looks like the pre-flight OPTIONS request is coming back OK. The browser actually tried to proceed with the following POST request. Under "POST General headers" you mention "Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error"  - where are you reading this from? Could it be that your server is just error-ing out, and the CORS error is a red herring?

Comment: Solved the issue, the service account my client was using in hosted environment didn't have the permission/role specified here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/creating-signatures

Although the localhost used the same service account, I'm still not sure how this worked in localhost.